# CSS transition of div on hover over only part of div?

Tags: css, html, css-transitions

Let me see how well I can explain this. I am working on an index on a website that is in a div that is pushed off of the page via css margin with only part of it showing. When you hover over the part that is showing, the rest slides down into view. This works fine. I already have the transition effect in place for the margin change slide and also a background color change with rgba. It looks very nice.

My question is, the index is around 500px wide and the visible part before hovering is 70px high. So that is a fairly large area of the screen for people to accidentally catch with their mouse hover if they are not trying to display the index div. Is there some way that I can only make part of the initially visible portion of the div activate the hover transition animation to bring the full div into view? Or perhaps someway I can attach a smaller div to this one as a sort of tab, that will bring down the larger div and itself via transition on hover?

I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Here is the basic idea of the current code:

```
#index {
    position:fixed;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin:-430px 0 0 -500px;
    transition:0.5s;
    -moz-transition:0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s;
    -o-transition:0.5s;}

#index:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    margin:0 0 0 -500px;}
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have working?  Ideally if you could put it into a jsfiddle.

Comment: Updated the question to include the code.

Comment: Good explanation, I understand fully. But a jsfiddle.net example would be _golden_ here. CSS and HTML.

Comment: jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Y3px6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jsFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/wZ8zX/1/

**html:**

```
<div id="slider"><div id="trigger"><br></div></div>
```

**js:**

```
$('#trigger').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({'top':0},500); 
});
$('#slider').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({'top':-150},500); 
});
```

---

solution without jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/wZ8zX/3/

sorry i usually just browse jquery questions, so i didn't check the tags lol

Comment: Works! :) Just for personal interest: there is no way to do that in css only, because there is no parent selector? Right? I was trying to achieve something similar once, but without parent selector it seemed impossible.

Comment: Did I miss the jQuery tag on this question?

Comment: Great, thanks. This jsFiddle is quite nice. I have not used it before. I will see if I can implement this suggestion with my page. It would be nice, as the comment above suggests, to be able to do it with only CSS.

Comment: No, you did not miss the jQuery tag, as it was asked as a CSS question. However, the answer suggested uses jQuery to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @Andy: Trolldiv! So easy and yet brilliant! I will def. keep in mind to use dummy elements in the future for things like this. Thanks a lot for sharing that idea!

Comment: Great, thanks again. I appreciate the CSS option. Maybe it is going right by me, but can you explain how this works? Does it have to do with z-index values?

Comment: @Andrej well it's not exactly elegant but it works and i couldn't think of another easy way

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like you are covering part of the hoverable element with a clear element. Sorry, it did go right past me at first. Thanks again.

Comment: @user981178 yes, i overlay the slider div with a transparent div. on hover of the non-overlaid area the slider slides down and changes the z-index so it is above the overlay div now. (hope this was somewhat understandable :) )

Comment: @user981178: just a small note: when Andy´s answer was what you were looking for (and i guess it was), than you can accept that answer by clicking the check mark beside his answer! (and sorry for adding so much comments - I just felt that I had to add that)

Answer (score 1):

Using only CSS you can use another block, or a pseudo-element to overlay the parts of block where you don't want to have transition, and then, after hover, make z-index for the element with transition bigger than overlaying element, so all the contents of it would be accessible.

Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/Y3px6/1/

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the position:relative property. I strongly feel that your current div tag has position relative property. Please remove that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).